# Sefer Haicholos

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, torah-service

Does anyone have a link to where it says in the sefer Haicholos that it's a special time to daven during the pesicha of the aron kodesh of 3 sifrai torah like this past week?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70238/759

Comment: http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/merkava/hechalot_rabati.htm

Comment: A wikipedia [link](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%94)

Comment: welcome Yossi! can you explain what so special?

Comment: Personally, I searched but couldn't find anything

Comment: @kouty so from your link we see this quote does not exist.

Comment: @user6591 Sorry, I just see the link, I never read a word in pirkey Heichalot,

Comment: @kouty I just skimmed through it. I didn't see it mentioned there.

Comment: who told you that such a heicholos exists?

Comment: @rabbi the week of Shabbos HaChodesh a story about the Gerrer Rebbe circulated citing sefer Heicholos about this concept. I also have not found it there.