# Davening for requests on Shabbos

Tags: tefilla, shabbat

I have read that davening for personal requests is forbidden on Shabbos due to being relaxed on Shabbos and not wanting to cause stress. However, being unable to daven for things and feeling like I can’t discuss my needs gives me stress during my Shabbos davening or even during rest times on Shabbos. Would the Halacha be different if davening for my personal requests on Shabbos would actually give me more relaxation?

Comment: I do not have an answer for you, but as I understand it in addition to not wanting to cause stress, we refrain from making requests on Shabbat to give Hashem a "rest" just as He rested on the 7th day of creation

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Can you please give a source for what you read in your first sentence?

Comment: ' The Yerushalmi Shabbat 15:3 78b writes that it is forbidden to ask for requests on Shabbat. The Korban Haedah explains that it is because as part of Oneg Shabbat a person should consider that all of his needs are taken care of and making requests shows that isn't the case and it indeed furthers his anxiety'

Comment: From http://rabbikaganoff.com/personal-supplications-on-shabbos-and-yom-tov/: Others prohibit praying for personal requests on Shabbos because it violates one’s oneg Shabbos. Praying for personal needs causes one to focus on what troubles him, which leads a person to be sorrowful (see Rambam, Hilchos Shabbos 30:12 and Ran, Shabbos, Rif page 5b). Shabbos is to be a day of joy.

Comment: @Daniel Note that any clarifications or additional details  should be edited into the post itself, rather than left as comments.

Comment: related: [Davening for personal matters on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70238/11501)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Daniel and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!